# Is there any way of limiting the matchable classes for data in SVMs?

Tags: svm, scikit-learn

Let's say I'm working on the "[Recognizing hand-written digits](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html)" where we are using an SVM to analyze handwritten digits. Now imagine we have some additional information, for each image we are also given a subset of numbers where we know for certain the answer lies among them. This is true for both training and test data.

ex: An image of the figure "4" is paired with the subset `{1, 3, 4, 7}`.

I'm using the scikit-learn implementation in my work. Is there any way of helping the training and/or testing with this data? Would another method be more suitable to use with this data?

I am fairly new to ML so all ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Is the true label known for each image in the training set?

Comment: Yes, it is. My actual dataset has several hundred labels. So restricting the allowed labels would be of great help.